# H letter is not working in vs code free version, how to rectify

Tags: visual-studio-code

'H' Letter is not working in VS Code. when the letter is typed, it displays the message "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'collapseAll')". I'm using windows 11 and vs code version 1.66(latest 2022) I'm not using any extensions. Solution, please.

Comment: Could be this is an error from one of the extensions you have installed (for example a code completion provider which has a problem). So try to deactivate all installed extension and check again.

Comment: on the key binding doc page is an item on how to debug key binding problems